# How to make timestamp appear based on data input in Column A?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

Based on Column A, I want the timestamp to populate Column B. The first half of the code works where the data is copied and pasted into another sheet. But the timestamp does not appear.

```
​function copyrange() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(Sheet1); //source sheet

  var testrange = sheet.getRange('A:A'); //range to check

  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());

  var csh = ss.getSheetByName(Sheet1); //destination sheet

  var data = [];

  var j =[];
```

Condition check in H:H; If true copy the same row to data array

```
for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {

  if ( testvalue[i] == 'Paid') {

  data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,25).getValues());

  //Copy matched ROW numbers to j

  j.push(i);

 }

 }

//Copy data array to destination sheet  
 csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

Delete matched rows in the source sheet

```
  for (i=0;i<j.length;i++){

  var k = j[i]+1;

  sheet.deleteRow(k);
```

Alter j to account for deleted rows

```
  if (!(i == j.length-1)) {

  j[i+1] = j[i+1]-i-1;

}

}

}

​var COLUMNTOCHECK = 0;

// Where you want the date-time stamp offset from the input location. [row, column]

var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,1];
```

Sheet you are working on

```
var SHEETNAME = Sheet1

function onEdit(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  //checks that we're on the correct sheet.

  if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) { 

    var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
```

Checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the date to appear.

```
    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) { 

      var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[1],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);

      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is failing at line 3 `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(Sheet1);` because the name of the sheet must be a string. Change it to `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");` Repeat anywhere else you use `getSheetByName()`

Comment: 1) Please share a copy of your spreadsheet (excluding any private or confidential material. 2) You said that "The first half of the code works where the data is copied and pasted into another sheet."  Please edit your question to supply the actual code that you are using - the code supplied does NOT and will NOT work; perhaps you have unsuccessfully tried to tailor it for this question. 3) "But the timestamp does not appear." This is not really helpful observation - please edit your question to include a copy of the Execution transcript.